# model.matrix correlations of discrete

Tags: r, correlation, experiment-design, matrix

I have the following full factorial design and I would like to evaluate the factors independency.

```
wp <- expand.grid(Temp = c(15, 20, 25) ,
                  Block = c('D1', 'D2', 'D3') )
```

To do that I would like to check the correlations between the variables(and get something similar to what JMP software is giving me.)

[image]

So, do to that I'm working with model.matrix and cor functions.

```
model.matrix(~ 1 + Temp * Block, data = wp) %>% cor

             (Intercept)     Temp    BlockD2    BlockD3 Temp:BlockD2 Temp:BlockD3
(Intercept)            1       NA         NA         NA           NA           NA
Temp                  NA 1.000000  0.0000000  0.0000000    0.1400280    0.1400280
BlockD2               NA 0.000000  1.0000000 -0.5000000    0.9701425   -0.4850713
BlockD3               NA 0.000000 -0.5000000  1.0000000   -0.4850713    0.9701425
Temp:BlockD2          NA 0.140028  0.9701425 -0.4850713    1.0000000   -0.4705882
Temp:BlockD3          NA 0.140028 -0.4850713  0.9701425   -0.4705882    1.0000000
```

I'm not sure if I have to keep the intercept or not but in any case I'm getting results that both I don't understand and they don't agree with JMP.
As it is a full factorial design the main factors and their interactions have to be independent but I can't see this from here.
I tried different contrasts just in case but I didn't find a solution. JMP's parameterisation should look [like this](https://www.jmp.com/support/help/en/16.2/#page/jmp/ordinal-factors.shtml#)

[image]

My question is,
**Why the variables from model.matrix are correlated?**

Thank you

Comment: "As it is a full factorial design the main factors and their interactions have to be independent" `Temp` is not encoded as a factor in your R code. It is continuous. And maybe it actually should be continuous.

Comment: @Roland, indeed I wanted to make an example between continuous and discrete. In the case of two discrete variables I still have the same problem with a bigger model matrix.

Comment: I don't understand why you expect zero correlations when you have a continuous predictor.

Comment: Well, I would expect to have independent factors since it's full factorial design. That't why I would expect to have zero correlation.

Comment: Also, JMP's output seems to agree with my expectations. Why, wouldn't you expect that?

Comment: Again, you have a continuous predictor. Are you simply looking for `wp$Temp <- factor(wp$Temp)`?

Comment: After all the function alias {stats} seems to be doing the job. Now need to figure out how this works

Answer (score 0):

Here https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v085i05 in section 7 (with a very similar example in 7.2) explains what is takes to estimate the factors independence.

In sort, it's about using orthogonal coding,

[image]